# Image attachment with delivery email

Tags: email, magento, attachment

I am looking for a way to attach an image with shipped confirmation email in Magento. There are few threads on pdf attachments but in my case I want to attach an image from 'media' folder with the email. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: please supply some examples of the code that you have tried so we can help you with a specific solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick question: is the image the same every time or specific to a customer order? I presume it is different or you wouldn't be asking.

To clarify: attachments are okay if you sending out invoices/delivery notes/order confirmation. However you are advised to setup your email so that the IP address can be verified directly. You are also advised to use a SPFrecord in your DNS so that the remote mail server can check that your server is allowed to send emails for you. Furthermore, in your order success page you can also ask your customers to add you to their address book, in that way your emails will not be marked as SPAM, regardless of whether you have SPF records and things setup.  The only thing is you cannot guarantee customers will do that, so the SPF records and the IP reverse lookup is best. You can also use DomainKeys DKIM for the likes of Yahoo mail - mail delivery isn't what this question is about so you will have to Google DKIM for yourself...

Otherwise, attaching an image is simple. See the example at the top of the page of the Zend  Programmers Reference Guide on attachments:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.attachments.html

Keep reading the comments for clarification on how to get the image data included.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Don't.  Attachments drop your deliverability numbers.

Simply setup your email as html and use an img src to a file located on any publicly available server.  No attachment required.

Comment: How would I do that? If I'm using sendEmail() in Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipping.php, how can I add html code there?